# Multi node.js instances - communication over HTTP

Tags: node.js, http

I'm currently writing an application which has sockets engine running on one node.js instance and restful API for various resources on other. I'm wondering what could be the best way (performance wise) to communicate between these to instances if they would be located on a different servers. I don't want to duplicate data access logic on different instances and I want to keep everything (what's related to data access) in one place.

1. I thought about using simple HTTP API where sockets engine would make request to resources instance and get what it asked for but I'm not sure if I won't hit any performance bumps. In fact I could actually connect straight to mongodb and get the data that I want from there without making a request to other service but I feel like it would be nice to isolate data so that could be only used by resources instance and that would be the only application that uses mongodb instance.
2. Is there any other better ways to achieve something similar?

Comment: well there are solutions, such as CouchDB with which you can access data via HTTP even client-side requests can query directly the database and with nothing in the middle.

Comment: But can you set authorization policies on couchDB? How do you deal with different permissions and how do you know later who changed the data?

Comment: i haven't had great experience with CouchDB , i myself, started about a month, it seems that you can manage read/write/update/delete permissions by authorizing with a cookie, you can have better results, with views though, also there are document that have revisions, so updating the username to have the value of the user logged in on updating the document will give you "who edited this"